# Please answer in detail along with references to support your answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Since past few days, am observing that the new users are answering short answers on the questions which looks more like a comment rather an answer.

I will provide few examples to refer, I will write the answers along with link (just in case if I delete them in near future)

1. [Should we consider ISKCON devotees as Hindus or not?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2759/124)
   ISKCON is not the sole representative of Krishna worship. And yes they are also Hindus or followers of the Sanatan Dharma. - [Reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2761/124)
2. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2757/124
   Never heard of any such custom. But no it is not supported by the scriptures. - *Now Deleted by Me*.
3. [Did Kaurav's son participate in the Mahabharata battle?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2715/124)
   Yes, Kaurav's sons also participated in battle which is mentioned in poem we had in school. A Poem was based on Abhimanyu and he killed Duryodhan's grand son. - [Reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2731/124)
4. [Did Kaurav's son participate in the Mahabharata battle?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2715/124) 
   The Bhagwad Gita's opening chapter, Arjunavishadayoga says, Arjuna was grieved to see his brothers, sons, nephews, sons-in-law and other relatives arrayed in battle against him. Clearly his nephews are the descendants of Kauravas - [Reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2724/124)
5. [Is human the ultimate species according to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2714/124)
   Humans are considered as ultimate species because only humans have power to spirituality. Only humans have 7 chakras and kundalini. Thus only human body is able to help the atma to attain moksh. - [Reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2716/124)

And I could just go on with this list. I seen an issue here. Such posts are more like comments instead of answer.

**So what do we expect from our users?**

We expect that you answer a question in detailed manner and **not in a run-and-gun** way...
A detailed answer is something which is written in brief, firstly it provides a background for the questions topic if necessary, then we should write our answer which further consists of reasons/claims/beliefs/your opinion etc which further should be supported with reference.

A reference can be a post on an authentic blog, or a scripture reference is what the user who questioned will appreciate.

**Do I need to write every answer in brief?**

Well, **NO**, not each and every answer of yours should be in brief. Adding unnecessary or irrelevant details to your answer wouldn't help anyone. Hinduism is a vast religion. Behind every question there is always a meaning which can be described briefly, if not, then too, try to explain in detail and provide references.

**What if I don't have enough privileges to comment?**

If you keep answering such short answers, other users tend to flag those answers of yours because of comment like answer and also low quality for the site which later gets deleted either by the community or by a moderator.

So wait till you get comment privileges, till then, visit a question, see if you can answer nicely, if yes, go ahead, answer it, and gain reputation points which will give you privileges. If you want to comment but you can't, the best you can do is, move to the next post and see if you can answer that.

Also, you can always answer old posts, there is no such thing like an answer is already accepted so why should I answer? So here the question comes is "Is my answer any different and correct from the answers which are already posted?" - If the answer for this question is yes, then go ahead and answer the old questions as well.

**What if users still answer like this?**

For all users : We want to build this site as a collection of solid resource over Hinduism. So we expect the users to contribute quality posts to the site. Its not always about the reputation, its about the community. Peer review posts, flag if you find low quality posts, comment and help new users rather than dropping a down vote and commenting nothing, which will not help the user at all, also that will turn off the users and eventually will leave because of this behavior.

For users who answer low quality : Your answers will be deleted by community or a moderator will delete your answer (will also convert into a comment if its useful).

**What should I do if my answer got deleted or converted into a comment?**

You can always see your recently deleted answers on - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/YOUR_ID

Replace YOUR_ID with your profile id which you will find on your profile page in the address bar, for example :

[image]

Over here, **124** is my id so the URL now will be

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/124 for me.

Here, you can always refer your deleted answers by you or a moderator, now you can edit them, and after you edit with relevant information, flag the moderator for an undelete and he will do the needful.

---

New user? Please [refer this answer to know how to answer questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-for-answering-questions/126#126)

Need inspiration or examples of quality answers on the site?

- [Example 1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-pre-determined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma)
- [Example 2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/550/what-exactly-was-the-chakra-vyuha-in-the-mahabharatha-and-why-did-abhimanyu-fai)
- [Example 3](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/924/124)
- [Example 4](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/264/why-are-temples-devoted-to-brahma-so-rare/267#267)
- [Example 5](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/905/124)
- [Example 6](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/93/124)
- [Example 7](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/222/124)

---

Still got any questions or any suggestions/comments over this? Feel free to provide one by answering this question.

Comment: I want to suggest new users to join chat rooms if they can't comment. I know they need 20+ rep to chat in chat rooms but as a Hinduism chat-room owner I will try to provide exception for them if they are interested to contribute.

Comment: @Mr_Green Room owners can't provide explicit write access to users less than 20rep. Only mods reserve the power to do so.