# I found answers in comment section, is it right pattern?

Tags: discussion

Considering this [link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2801/were-any-of-vishnus-avatars-besides-kalki-foretold-in-advance) as an example

I have seen many such links where users actually put a valid point in comments. And that too a answer in short.

This gives no use to the question, the question still seems unanswered and goes into the unanswered section of the blog. Secondly, it drops down the percentage of answered questions of the community.

I a person has a valid point he can elaborate it and make it a valid answer, rather than leaving it to just a comment.

Comment: They might have no sources for their claims and they might  just helping other users (_for remembering_) who could answer it.

Comment: @Mr_Green, ok got it, and thanks.

Comment: Many answers are perfectly valid, but do not meet the "guidelines" set by stack exchange. Thus it is posted as comments.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Its fine to post comments if user cannot answer in detail, but if he is confident enough to answer the question then he should answer instead of commenting

---

You yourself answered your own question "*answer in short*" so we don't want our users to answer in short (comment like) and hence they end up posting a comment.

Now is this good? No, posting answers as comments is not a good thing, but if a user is not confident enough to post as an answer, it is completely fine to post as a comment, it will somewhat help the user to refer something rather than the user posting a wrong answer which further affects the quality of the site.

Users generally comment or should comment when :-

- They need any clarifications from the user who questioned
- They are not sure about the whole question but still want to help a user with a part of his question
- They don't know the answer but still want to add something to the post
- Falsify any claims / information provided by a user in his question
- Cannot answer in detail **(important)**

Users should post the comments if they cannot answer in detail, just like [I mentioned in my previous post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/please-answer-in-detail-along-with-references-to-support-your-answers?cb=1), so even if user tries to answer in 2-3 lines and it is not much useful, his answer will be down voted (probably) and will be deleted eventually.

So if users should answers if they are sure enough to explain the OP in detail, if not, it is recommended to leave an helpful comment if he knows some part of the question.

Comment: I wish new users were able to post comments; that might lessen the problem of them posting one-line answers to questions.