# Written proof is significant but Myth and verbal facts are also important to know the Dharma

Tags: discussion

Hindu Dharma has a vast community, there are many stories for the same incident, vary from location and situations. So asking for the Written proof for each word we write, is not a fair enough.

We read, hear and listen so many stories and we like to share it based on our beliefs and I think that's the whole purpose of the question seeker, to get all kind of stories for the same event.

I have seen  a particular user ( *Keshav Srinivasan* )  always comments and demands for proof. I want to say in simple way that We Hear/ read and share , if you knew more stories then it's better for the knowledge. I didn't read all the things from vedas and I dont have even enough time to search the proof.

and If I wrote something in Hindi then what's wrong? Hindu is written in Sanskrit and Hindi is daughter of Sanskrit.

Kindly avoid such users who tries to being the moderator and comments over each answer. Hinduism is vast and all Hindus heard from many sources. If you find something wrong then you can ask.

Note: after Today's incident he down voted my answers repeatedly. Please do something positive for this kind of activity

Thanks.

Comment: No, I haven't engaged in any serial downvoting against you.  I think I did downvote your answer where you posted in Hindi though.  If you improve your answer, I'm happy to remove the down vote.

Comment: `We read, hear and listen so many stories and we like to share it based on our beliefs and I think that's the whole purpose of the question seeker, to get all kind of stories for the same event.` completely disagree with you.. Whatever we heard could be rumors. This site discourage sharing knowledge based on rumors. if you read scripts then we are ready to learn from you. I hope you can understand :)

Answer (score 5):

Let me break your question into separate pieces... So first I'll explain you about this part :-

*I didn't read all the things from vedas and I dont have even enough time to search the proof.*

Here, this is the exact reason why not only him but most of the active users asks for a scripture reference rather than a proof. The reason why we ask scripture references because as you said, Hinduism is a vast religion, with thousands of beliefs and too many version of the same stories. Inorder to maintain the quality state on the site and the content authenticity we request our users to backup their answers either with scripture reference or you can also link your post to a website which provides similar information.

Now am saying link to the site, so please don't copy paste it straight away. As you said that you didn't read all the things from Vedas hence you should either ask questions or you should start learning about vedas, if you think you are professional or too good in Hinduism then you should consider answering but if you are a learning user, surely you can answer but please provide some references to backup your claims, it helps users to refer answers.

Similar Posts :-

- [Please answer in detail along with references to support your answers](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271/)
- [Let us stop asking for "Sources" every time](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/)

---

Coming to *and If I wrote something in Hindi then what's wrong? Hindu is written in Sanskrit and Hindi is daughter of Sanskrit.*

Well, there is no issue if you write a part of your answer in Hindi or Sanskrit **BUT** we are on the internet, the site is intended to target not only Hindus but anyone who is interested in Hinduism or its topics so think of an American user reading Hindi/Sanskrit and he wont get a bit of what you are writing in your answer so answering should be in English, if you want to share a Sanskrit snippet from our scriptures, it is completely fine but make sure you explain them in English as well..

---

*Kindly avoid such users who tries to being the moderator and comments over each answer.*

He is not a moderator, trying to help users or keeping the site doesn't mean that he acts as a moderator but you can say that he is helping to keep the site clean and on topic instead. If he down votes any of your answers, take necessary action, provide references and he will retract his votes back.

I am keeping a check on the voting patterns of most of the active users so never think that anyones playing unfair here. If you feel fishy about votes then instead of raising a question on meta you can contact a moderator by flagging any random post and writing a message to check the vote patterns.

---

*After today's incident he down voted my answers repeatedly. Please do something positive for this kind of activity*

As I said, am keeping a check on users activity, if we think that the user is playing unfair we will surely revert their votes back but they are not out of envy but with a reason. Also you cannot be sure that he has voted all the down votes you've scored.