# Answering and Questioning format, mythological names usage?

Tags: discussion

I know this kind of question been previously posted with very good answer, but I would like to post it as a extention of [that](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-for-answering-questions).

**Firstly** whenever I used caps to symbolize strictness in my words, those are capsed down, can't I use caps in my answers?

**Secondly**, I saw many people using words like *Rama*, *Ravana*, *Hanumana*. Most of them have a ending note of '*ae*' with them which is not in the actual form. If go in sanskrit Ram should be pronounced as *Ramah(ah = :)*, going to hindi it should be Ram or Raam.

The use of Ending **'ae'** was started by english men, because they were encapable of pronouncing **(:)**, and they ended up using **'ae'**, and not only this , their english language doesn't have a subsitute of **(:)**, so they blindly use **'a'** at indian historic names.

We being knowledged a lot in this field should consider to propogate right things but not repeat the faults happend long ago, and by someone who is blind.

Sorry I'm not rational to english, because its another way to spread the knowledge, but we should have a liable freedom to use *safe* words than *sound* words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Whenever I used caps to symbolize strictness in my words, those are capsed down, can't I use caps in my answers?*

You can certainly capitalize the words where it is required, for example a name of a person, a place etc but say you capitalize like, will be removed obviously.

> this is Just a sentence where I have Weird capitalization so Users
>   will remove this because This is incorrect.

---

Coming to your second question, its good that you pointed out the spelling issues, where we compare Sanskrit and English. Now am not sure whether *Ram* is a correct translation of Sanskrit as I can't read that. But, we are on the internet, big sites like Wikipedia, [Vedabase](http://vedabase.com/en/rkd/appendix-1-story-of-tiver-ganges) etc spell the word as `Rāma`.

**Search Engine Matters**

If you search the word [Ram](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ram&oq=ram&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i61j69i59j69i61j0.3166j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) compared to [Rama](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rama&oq=rama&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i61j69i60l2j69i61j0.845j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) there is a huge difference. So? should we use wrong words just to get help users find better? No, am not saying to use wrong words, but use generalized terms which are used on the internet. It helps user to find better. Also am not even sure that Rama is a wrong word, I don't think Rama is wrongly spelled.

**We are not writing posts for India only**

I see many users on the website from different countries. Some are scholars in Hinduism, some are enthusiast to learn about Hinduism. A user will search on the Internet before he asks a question and he will encounter words like `Rama`, the one with `a` in the end and he will use that word in his post. So its better to look from everyone's point of view and not just the way Indians spell these words.

**Conclusion**

Use generalized terms which are used on major websites, also keep consistency in using spellings in your posts. Users shouldn't use Rama and Ram interchangeably.

Comment: Aliesn, I am convinced by your answer, but one of my question http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/2803/revisions, was revised, in which most errors being CASES. Why?

Comment: @KCloud Uppercase was not required, infact capitalization is also not required at some places... when you write uppercase words it feels like you are shouting. Its better to *emphasize* your words along with *Capitalization* if required which looks decent compared to UPPERCASE ...

Comment: got it and in paralell

Comment: @KCloud If you need more help on formatting, [refer this page](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: @KCloud I at least typically use *Italics* for words that are from Sanskrit and might have alternate transliterations, and **Bold** for emphasizing important points. Also, I don't think spelling is a huge issue as long as you are consistent (and reasonable) across your own posts.

Comment: "I don't think Rama is wrongly spelled."  Yes, we should use Rama, it's the standard transliteration of the Sanskrit word.  And in general we should prefer Sanskrit spellings like Rama and Shiva over Hindi or Tamil spellings, as I mentioned in this answer: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/233/36