# Can we have a suggestion for meta post "Guidelines for new users answering questions" at the answer popup?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, new-users

We often found that answers from new users are comments/opinions/lacking sources. So, we've to introduce [how to answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and Guidelines like citing sources to them.

When a new user first time writes answer to a question, system popups the following suggestion:

> [image: screenshot]

Now It would be very useful if system propose/suggest meta question [Guidelines from new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/277) because that post is aimed to guide newbies for this site.

So, **Can we include that link [Guidelines from new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/277) in the mentioned popup?** something like:

[image: improved]

Comment: Super useful suggestion.. but I would say, *But avoid*'s second statement is kind of redundant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok.

[image: Image of the additional link in the new-user answering advice pop-up]

Comment: That was fast..

Comment: If you could move that under the first bullet it would be even better.

Comment: I posted a [follow up question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1262/9125) on this one. Can you answer that question please?