# To which users is the "Guidelines for new users" pop up is shown?

Tags: support, answers, new-users

There is a site specific feature for us. That is the popup of suggesting guidelines for new users. [Can we have a suggestion for meta post "Guidelines for new users answering questions" at the answer popup?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/876/9125)

My question is not about why it is shown (it is for attracting quality answers) but to which users it is shown. The proposed suggestion is for the users who are answering a question for the first time. But this is shown to users who have already given one upvoted answer.

[image: Image showing "Guidelines to new users" pop up]

If it is same proposed in the question, then it should not show to me. From that it can be known that it is shown to other users besides the users who are answering for the first time. There is not much detail from Shog

So, I want to know to which users it is shown? Is there a reputation threshold where the system stops showing the pop up? What is the criteria?

I think the criteria used for Late answers review is applied here. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originally planned as a part of EULA: [Heuristics for detecting a bad answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72523/260388) in late 2010.

> If the score is below a (configurable) threshold, we will present the user with an [answer EULA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) and some basic help

Meanwhile [feature-requested](/questions/tagged/feature-requested): [Add informative dialog for users posting first-time answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86423/260388)

Which was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and declared: [Suggest dynamic help text for new answerers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86576/260388) in April 2011.

According to which, it's shown for new users having reputation less than 100.

> We now have dynamic answer help that pops up **for new users (< 100 rep)** when they focus the answer box.

Comment: You may also refer [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86827/260388).

Comment: Does this 100 include association bonus? I think that should be shown for them because they are as new as 1 rep users when comes to answering on site.

Comment: @User9125 need to verify. However I think yes, that includes association bouns as SE trust on him/her and s/he would know how to answer.