# Are Irawati Karve's books/works valid references for answers on this site?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, sources-and-citations

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irawati_Karve):

> Irawati Karve (15 December 1905 – 11 August 1970) was an
> anthropologist, sociologist, educationist and writer from Maharashtra,
> India.

One of her books, is used as a reference in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17563/4732).

My question is are books written by this author have any authority on this site to be used in answers? I highly doubt that to be the case.

Comment: The other meta post solution will be really helpful to decide this as well. IMO, it should not be. I don't think modern thoughts have anything to do with Hinduism which is an ancient religion.

Comment: "The other meta post solution will be really helpful to decide this as well" Which post are you talking about? And thanks for your response. @Mr_Green

Comment: oh sorry, I meant this one: [Questions asking whether something is an interpolation are opinion based and not appropriate for this site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1983/93)

Comment: Okay thanks @Mr_Green

Comment: We really need to identify people whose work reference can be used to cite sources. We should only allow works of those people who studied scripture as per Dharma like under some Guru's guidance etc. Otherwise answers from these  anthropologist will only bring chaos.

Comment: So are you giving your reason for the downvote in that comment? @idolworshipper

Comment: Oh I see @idolworshipper

Comment: You can expand your comment to an answer @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: You can expand your comment to an answer if you wish @Mr_Green

Answer (score 2):

We should have a proper discussion to draw this line of which scriptures to allow and which not. But since you clearly mentioned the period which falls under the modern period, I propose we should not consider the works of this Author. I have nothing against this author or any other modern author, it is just I strongly feel modern authors have nothing to do with Hinduism.

To be more clear, the modern author's works should not be considered.

The following are fine irrespective of time:

- Pure translation works.
- Sthala puranas

[My comment above:](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/are-irawati-karves-books-works-valid-references-for-answers-on-this-site/1994?noredirect=1#comment9380_1990)

> I think translations are fine but not when the scriptures were mixed it with the author's own thoughts (interpolations?). I understand even Tulsidas did it in Ramacharitmanas but those books are what defined Hinduism, unlike modern books. I am just not sure where to draw this line exactly. But I am pretty sure we should not consider 1900s work i.e even Swami Vivekananda's (maybe it is allowed on phylosophy.se but not here).

Comment: Its not so much about the timeline. For example, Ramana Maharishi, Ramakrishna etc. are all modern day saints but their opinions have authority on this site or in any Hinduism related discussion. Because they all have practiced the religion, spirituality. Its about whether a particular author has any qualifications to hold an authoritative opinion on religion or not.

Comment: Knowledge of Sanskrit is not a benchmark, because this is not a site about Sanskrit language (pure Sanskrit Qs are regarded off topic here). Its like you can be well versed in English but you won't be able to understand anything in a Physics paper even if that is written in English unless you are a Pundit in Physics.

Comment: So you have to be a Pundit in spirituality, Religion, Hinduism to be considered an authority on this site. Question is if the author here has any Punditva in aforementioned matters or not.

Comment: `So you have to be a Pundit in spirituality, Religion, Hinduism to be considered an authority on this site` I feel that is opinion-based. IMO, we should consider Ramana Maharishi too in phylosophy.se - nothing respectfully wrong in it. There are already some good Q&A on philosophy.SE site on Ramana maharishi.

Comment: Who is Nityananda to start with? @idolworshipper

Comment: There are already some good Q&A on that site on Ramana maharishi -- You mean on this site or on Philosophy.SE? @Mr_Green

Comment: philosophy.se.. updated.

Comment: Also it is not subjective. Scriptures, which are our main sources here, clearly mention who all are qualified to read, analyse scriptures like Vedas, Agamas. So it is objectively clear that some people are already ruled out. Then we have to discuss about the rest. @idolworshipper

Comment: @idolworshipper And, its not only about spirituality too, its about Hinduism a religion. Just like you have to practice medicine to have an opinion on the subject to be held with any value by the medical community its the same here with Hinduism.

Comment: I am not sure of the exact date but as I see Hinduism is ancient. Nothing has been added recently (modern) which could make it more clear than what is already there. As I see, modern works have more to do with one's interpolations - spiritual or philosophical. I think this doesn't apply to translations and Sthala puranas.

Comment: I am not sure about interpretations as I am not up to that level. But I feel that should be welcomed. This will definitely raise questions to differentiate between interpretations and interpolations. This is a good point and a "must-have" discussion among experts on this site.

Answer (score -1):

As I tried explaining it to you in the [Moderation Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55556685#55556685), as long as the citation addresses the question at hand it can be a valid reference for the site.

> **Rickross**: @Pandya Are sources/books like the one used in the above answer valid? I think its time we draw a line.
>
> **sv.**: I'm just curious. How do you draw this line? On what basis should the sources/books used be disallowed?
>
> If the person saying the same thing is Swami Vivekananda and the book cited is Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, then it should be allowed? **So we should focus on who is saying it and not what is being said?**
>
> Why don't you propose this new rule on Meta?

That is what [this FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126) says:

> In the absence of any scriptural reference, written works of scholars, researchers and popular personalities can be used which must be **providing a relevant answer**.

It doesn't say, the scholar needs to be Hindu, Indian, initiated (to read, translate and comment on the Vedas), etc. The only requirement is that the answer be relevant to what is being asked.

AFAIK, neither Stack Exchange nor this site currently discriminate authors based on gender, nationality, religion or political affiliations, so we don't keep a whitelist/blacklist of authors and publications.

This isn't the first time this issue has come up. A few users even had problem with answers citing works of modern/controversial gurus:

- [Validity of references from new-age Gurus?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/537/validity-of-references-from-new-age-gurus)
- [Should we allow words of Swamis as sources who face (legal) allegations?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1295/should-we-allow-words-of-swamis-as-sources-who-face-legal-allegations)

So if you don't like Iravati Karve and her works, you can downvote answers that cite her all you want. But banning some authors (just like modern gurus) simply because some users don't like their views/conclusions may get SE staff involved in the workings of this site.

---

> *We really need to identify people whose work reference can be used to cite sources. We should only allow works of those people **who studied scripture as per Dharma like under some Guru's guidance etc**. Otherwise answers from these anthropologist will only bring chaos. – TheLittleNaruto [5 hours ago](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/are-irawati-karves-books-works-valid-references-for-answers-on-this-site#comment9340_1989)*

So all modern translations of Vedas, Upaniṣads, Gītā, etc. especially by Westerners should be disallowed too? Example:

- [The Rigveda: 3-Volume Set by Stephanie W. Jamison, Joel P. Brereton](https://books.google.com/books?id=fgzVAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [Upaniṣads by Patrick Olivelle](https://books.google.com/books?id=WJGL2tUm6P4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

And what about users who provide their own English translation of Sanskrit verses in their answers? Shouldn't they have "studied scripture as per Dharma like under some Guru's guidance"? How do we find out if these users are really qualified to write answers on this site? Even if they self-attest, should we just take their word for it? Maybe we should thoroughly vet all new users for their "Hinduness" before they are allowed to write answers on this site. Seems like a great way to run an SE site.

Comment: So you assumed that all westerners without studying scripture under some Guru guidance wrote translations?

Comment: I have noticed; you like to emphasize this word(westerners) a lot. I wonder what makes you do that. May be you have never met any initiated westerner Hindu. Also In the question body OP is talking about an Indian and not a westerner.

Comment: And I think OP is interested in drawing line in between whose work is allowed to provide the sources and whose not. It's not about westerners at all.  I think you got some agenda. What is your agenda?

Comment: I think translations are fine but not when the scriptures were mixed it with the author's own thoughts (interpolations?). I understand even Tulsidas did it in Ramacharitmanas but those books are what defined Hinduism, unlike modern books. I am just not sure where to draw this line exactly. But I am pretty sure we should not consider 1900s work i.e even Swami Vivekananda's (_maybe it is allowed on phylosophy.se but not here_).

Comment: You are right .. I am trying to know whether this particular author Karve is qualified to hold an authoritative opinion about Hinduism, religion or spirituality or not. Its not about the author's gender, ethnicity etc. So I don't understand why such irrelevant and misleading stuffs are present in this answer. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @idol Translation is not a problem here, it becomes a problem when one does their own analysis in order to deny any event which have occurred in itihasa or scripture. Hope this is clear to you now.

Comment: Even for translations they (westerners) rely on traditional Hindu scholars like Sayana and many others. Those are not their own translations at all.They simply have sufficient knowledge in Sanskrit to be able to translate original Sanskrit works/translations into English. @TheLittleNaruto And even whether they have correctly rendered (say) Sayana's work or not must be subject of investigation. We can not take them for granted.

Comment: @Rickross True! So we really need to setup a boundary here. Let's hope this discussion will bring a conclusive set of rules.

Comment: "So you assumed that all westerners without studying scripture under some Guru guidance wrote translations?" - did you look at the examples I gave? Have Stephanie W. Jamison, Joel P. Brereton and Patrick Olivelle learnt Sanatana Dharma under a guru before translating Vedas, Upanishads, Manu Smriti? Why do Western professors of Sanskrit and Hinduism need to be initiated? If you ban these authors and their translations, it's inherently racist and SE may shutdown this site forever. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @sv. I was guessing you have such agenda. Guess I was right. So you do have agenda to bring issues unnecessarily.

Comment: @sv. Read what I said here: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/are-irawati-karves-books-works-valid-references-for-answers-on-this-site/1990?noredirect=1#comment9399_1990

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto What agenda have I got? Are you saying all users on this site have to literally agree with everything stated in Itihasas and Puranas? Are you serious??!! So, if I only agree to some of them not everything, I have got an "agenda"?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Read what Swami Vivekananda said [here](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_6/epistles_second_series/124_sir.htm): "The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class and malice. Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love are acceptable, **the rest are to be rejected**." Do you have a problem if I follow this? Is that an "agenda"?

Comment: @sv. Agreement and Disagreement w.r.t. Purana/Itihasa has nothing to do what you said above. You're unnecessarily bringing term "westerners" "foreigners". I don't know why are you doing all these.

Comment: "You're unnecessarily bringing term westerners foreigners." - I only brought it up because of your comment under the post, remember, one thing leads to another. You said, "We should only allow works of those people who studied scripture as per Dharma like under some Guru's guidance etc." --- THIS automatically disqualifies a lot of Western/Foreign translations. Don't you get it? Now go back and read my answer w.r.t your comment and it will start making sense. It seems you have an agenda to ban all Western translations on this site, is that why you posted that comment? @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @sv. I also said translation is okay as long as translator "analysis" does not deny any event which have occurred in itihasa/scripture. And about that statement studied scripture under some guru applies equally be it an Indian or a foreigner. In the question body itself OP is talking about an Indian translator and not a foreigner. You are just proving my point that you got some agenda for sure otherwise you wouldn't have sticken to this word "westerner"

Comment: "I also said translation is okay as long as translator "analysis" does not deny any event which have occurred in itihasa/scripture." - who are you to tell a scholar how to interpret some aspect of Hinduism? So you'll only allow a source/interpretation that already agrees with you? Is this site some kind of banana republic? I think you've got a wrong idea of how SE sites work. People writes competing answers often with differing opinions. The most useful answer is decided by voting. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: "You are just proving my point that you got some agenda for sure otherwise you wouldn't have sticken to this word westerner" - you are also proving my point that you have an agenda against Westerners and Foreigners by constantly posting comments like this all over the site: "We should only allow works of those people who studied scripture as per Dharma like under some Guru's guidance etc." and there by denying users a chance to cite their works on Hinduism. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @sv. So back to comment 1, did you also assume that "all the westerners" who are associated with Hinduism are not studying scripture under some Guru? The way you kept using this westerner word, your answer looks "Yes"! Guess that makes you against them and not me. Because my comment is generalized, and yours is targeting a certain group of people which is against CoC.

Comment: No, I didn't, but your comment was a blanket statement against all Indian and Western scholars of Hinduism. Especially Western because they are only interested in studying Hinduism, not get initiated formally, their personal religion could be Christianity or they maybe Atheist or Agnostic. And in my answer I never said all Westerners automatically become ineligible based on the new criteria you propose. It is just your assumption. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @sv. haha! Dude you really want to play round and round. Don't you? How many times I'll have to reply with previous comments. Please read them before you put next comment. lol

Comment: Seriously, what kind of a rule is this: "We should only allow works of those people who studied scripture as per Dharma like under some Guru's guidance etc." Have you even given a serious thought to this? What if I say, your guru is a fake, he was not properly initiated, we don't recognize him as an authority on this site? Some Hindus may say, "Sai Baba is a fake. The Puttaparthi one, even more fake." So are you going to count the # of followers a guru has before allowing their works as references on this site?@TheLittleNaruto

Comment: The attempt to mislead users by hiding facts, intentionally highlighting certain facts, by play of words, by taking the name of SE policy etc. is not new. The same user tried to mislead the Meta community too. But his post eventually was destroyed by CMs there. So, I understand what you're trying to say here @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @Rickross I have flagged his comments for moderator. We shall wait.

Comment: Even in [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1991/4732) the user is bringing in the westerner angle "The more Western these historians are the more problematic it is for you to digest some of the things they say." But I will object in the same way even when any Indian would write something like that and if I find it in posts of this site. So, we can not rule out that your apprehension might be true. @TheLittleNaruto