# Was it reasonable to close this question as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, moderators, asking-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons

[Are both Shiva and Vishnu considered supreme as per Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36022/are-both-shiva-and-vishnu-considered-supreme-as-per-vedas)

This question has been put on hold as "primarily opinion-based" by a mod. The automatic reason stated in the banner is:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but **answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions**, **rather than facts, references**, or specific expertise.

The mod further explains his reasons for closing in comments:

> **What god(s) the Vedas declare is a subject that different sects of Hinduism disagree about**, so I’m closing your question for the time being. If you want to revise your question, then edit it and flag me to reopen it.

That different sects of Hinduism disagree about something doesn't seem like a valid reason to close questions. If this were true, the hundreds of questions on specific Bhagavad-gītā verses (see [example 1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8735) and [example 2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35054)) where several users have written answers based on their favorite philosophy need to be closed as well.

As I explained in [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1505) answer, there is another way to answers these questions using facts and references and without taking sides. And for this reason, such questions should be left open even if they generate a certain amount of controversy.

Comment: There is no good reason why this sort of questions will be left open. It was good that it was closed. Do you like peace or not?

Comment: I want peace enforced via moderation and not by closing valid objective questions which can be answered using scriptures. How is peace being maintained in these questions: ([Do any Vedic verses depict Lord Vishnu to be supreme?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19872) [Where do Vaishnava Scriptures declare Shiva as supreme god?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19497) [What scriptures describe Shiva discussing selling salt in the Banasura story?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27071)) Why aren't these old posts closed or locked? Peace only applies to new posts/users? @Rickross

Comment: Of the 3 Qs you linked only one created controversy and I remember users objecting about it .. that Q however can not be closed and the others are not detrimental to peace according to me. But why shd we allow the one you asked about? You try passing the bill but it's unlikely that it will be passed :P

Comment: @Rickross 'only one created controversy' - ok but why isn't that post locked or closed? Maybe you can write an answer defending the closure. 'But why should we allow the one you asked about?' - please read my question again. Some users who have [voted to reopen](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/36022/revisions) are not active on meta. So yeah, the bill may not pass. Also, remember that mods reversing their decisions on this site is another story altogether, votes do not seem to count.

Comment: Peace is when people are able to resolve their conflicts without violence and can work together to improve the quality of their lives.  What if there are opinion based answers?  If those answers are being supported by scriptural Base or interpretation of a saint,  I don't think there should be an objection. @Rickross

Comment: Even if supported by scriptural base,  some of my answers were downvoted.   It indicates narrow mentality on the part of some members,  who can't accept answers with different point of view.  So keeping in view of those narrow minded people, we shouldn't get scared, in my view,  and close some questions just taking resort on peace. @Rickross

Answer (score -3):

OP has now rephrased the question to the following. It now looks just like the [other one on Vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19872/do-any-vedic-verses-depict-lord-vishnu-to-be-supreme).

> [Do any vedic verses depicts Lord Shiva to be supreme?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36022/do-any-vedic-verse-depicts-about-lord-shiva-to-be-supreme)
>
> Are there are any verses in the Vedas which declare Lord Shiva to be supreme?

So maybe now it can be reopened.

Comment: Voting to reopening just to close again as a duplicate is waste of reviewer's time. [Which Vedic verses depict Lord Shiva/Rudra as the Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19831/5212) Perhaps a mod can look into it and close it again.  Better to ping a mod in comments and ask him to close. It is *exact* duplicate with title too and discouraged. Some research is required before posting.

Comment: It's close to the other one, but not an exact duplicate. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Please read both the questions again. That looks like a deliberate duplicate to me.

Comment: I've read all three and they are all one-liners which can be interpreted in many ways. What do you mean by deliberate duplicate? @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Deliberate duplicate is something which is asked intentionally. If something is interpreted in many ways, it is not a clear question. It is not eligible for reopening. I don't think those three questions can be interpreted in many ways. It is same along with usage of words.