# Can we increase the number of votes to close a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I understand that currently 5 votes are needed to close a question. Can we all agree to increase this number? Or is this a fixed number that cannot be changed?

Answer (score 5):

If the number of votes are to be increased *permanently*, it would be implemented across the network including the sites such as [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), [Super User](https://superuser.com) and even [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com). The bigger is the site, bigger is the review queue. It is to be noted not all users with enough privileges participate in user level moderation work since that's done voluntarily. Because of this reason the review queue would keep on growing and since a user with enough reputation can review 20 posts per day per queue, it may happen that the existing votes might just age away. Once votes are aged away you are allowed to cast a vote again after 10 days.

There have been multiple requests on Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange to decrease the number of votes required. I can't find all but two them are listed below.

1. [Reduce the number of votes required to close a question to 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348560/10785056)
2. [Huge close votes review queue on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151833/468333)

[An experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388313/10785056) was carried away on Stack Overflow to check if the efficiency increases if the votes are decreased. [Similar Experiment](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7723) was conducted on Software Engineering 4 years ago.

Well that said, none of the question asked to "increase" the number of votes. If you think that they should be increased, please explain why, so that "the company" would look into it. And please don't consider a single site. It may happen that this Community grows exponentially in future and then the scenario like Stack Overflow happens here too.

Comment: "If you think that they should be increased, please explain why". Because some people seem to be too eager to close questions.

Comment: @LazyLubber You can't change the whole system because of some people. Please consider community as a whole. I hope you understand.

Comment: @LazyLubber If tge question has two or three questions, if the question asks about some other religion, if the question asks a question which is already asked several times already, then the correct way is to be eager to close it. It's how the moderation works.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma All I was asking is - currently if 5 members feel that way, question is closed. Let more members feel the same way before the question can be closed. Anyway since this is not easy to implement, this discussion is academic.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, the number of votes should increase to at least 10 because the website is rigged.

This website should be named not as Hinduism Stack Exchange rather Vedanta Stack Exchange.

There is recorded proof of this bias on this website. The coterie is exposed in the "[Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)" See point 5. where the coterie has as the yardstick of "Prasthana" to measure the "correctness" of the answer.

Why should all the user be measured on the yardstick of Prasthana? This is a million-dollar question!

This is recorded evidence of the way the coterie groups together to judge an answer, downvote it, close the question and many other acts that point to the rigged practices on this website. The coterie supports each other to gain privileges.

Then these privileges are used to suppress other viewpoints! In real-world such practices will amount to infringement of Anti-trust laws and goes against the principles of natural justice.