# Has the Moderator "the destroyer" lost all interest in the site?

Tags: discussion, moderators, users

It seems that the moderator [The Destroyer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer) has lost all interest in participating on the site. His [last post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer?tab=activity&sort=posts) was on June 16, 2019. Considering the fact, he is one of the most actively participating users on the site, this is extremely strange.

And, he had not post any comment too between March 22 and September 22, 2020. Regarding, his moderation activities, I can not comment anything, as most of those are hidden from us.

So, the question is to him and other similar users (like Tejaswee and many many others) - Do you guys have lost all interest in participating in this site? If so please proclaim the same here so that the rest of us also can decide whether wasting our time and effort on the site, like how it is now, is at all worthy or not? The site is on the decline, with few agenda driven users dominating the site, whose motive is not to spread knowledge about Hinduism or learn about the same, but to demean it in any possible manner.

It is due to users like The Destroyer, Tejaswee, Triyugi Narayan Mani, Swiftpushkar and many others that this site has developed over the years into such a great site on Hinduism. If you guys have decided that that is enough or if you feel no interest at all in participating then it will be worthwhile to proclaim it openly here. My question is to all such users and not just the specific ones I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Good post.  If old timers have no interest in this site and with agenda driven users dominating the site, I am feeling of leaving the site.  Let me await the replies of old timers.

Comment: Yes looks like 99% of them have lost all interest and hope seeing how the site is right now. @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: Sensing this decline, I had already posted [my answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1929/3869) under my own question.  Now that you are sharing similar views, I think we have reached a state to say **Good bye** to this site. @Rickross

Comment: Let's see if we can churn out something positive @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: @Rickross, to clarify, are you saying that vaishnavas have an agenda ? Of course they have an agenda, just like Shaivites have an agenda, and Shaktists have an agenda. This agenda is called devotion / propagation of their own sect. I do not see anything wrong with someone quoting scriptures to back their 'agenda'. It just so happens that a seeming 'majority' of users belong to one sect. so what ? each sect is free to voice their opinions and users can follow what they want. we had same discussion about 'atheist' agenda. as long as they quote scriptures, that's all we can ask for.

Comment: Ok. I will wait for till 10-10-2020 (maximum).  If situation doesn't improve, I will take exit @Rickross

Comment: I am not talking about Vaishnavas here .. I have clearly said " whose motive is not to spread knowledge about Hinduism or learn about the same, but to demean it in any possible manner." Do you think that the Vaishnavas do that? @ram

Comment: oh ok, looks like you are talking about the atheistic answers here, and I agree with your stance on that one.. however, i believe @SrimannarayanaKV is talking about Vaishnavas 'agenda', so it looks like you two have a different idea of which 'sect' is agenda-driven.

Comment: Asking the right questions. Thanks. I wish he was active though.

Comment: One of the posts of @TheDestroyer came up on Google and i came to know about this site.. active participation is very much needed for site's growth..but sometimes it's difficult to give time here if we get overloaded with other stuffs..bdw, hope I m not in "few agenda driven users" list.. :)..

Comment: No you are not .. how do you think that you are in it? :D BTw what you said is absolutely right. @YDS

Comment: My post can not act as a motivation for you to leave the site :D @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: Actually, after observing the ruckus created by a group of members, and the prevailing chaotic situation in this site, I have been thinking of leaving the site for quite some time.  Your post had acted only as a catalyst to my thought process. @Rickross

Comment: Let's be patient and see if the situation improves or not. We can always decrease our activity anytime we want. Probably this site is currently running some malefic Dasha :D. A Pundit in astrology may be able to predict when things will improve or whether it will forever stay like this only. @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: @Rickross: Much before you  posted your Meta question now, I had heated debate with 2 members (Satya and idolworshipper (now kākatālīya)) under [this question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1987/3869).  Most of their comments were deleted either by the members by themselves or by the moderator.  In their comments those 2 members, hinted to move out of the site, **albeit subtly**, as my posts/comments have been causing inconvenience to their group of members.  So don't worry, your post is not the cause for my exit from this site.  Thanks for the support you have been extending to me

Comment: @Srimannarayana K V. None of my comments under that answer were deleted either by me or moderator. All I did was either to defend the path I follow or tried to explain how those quotes hurt Sri Vaishnavas. And nowhere I have interacted with you. Indeed I agreed to quote such citations. What you are saying is strange,fortunate that I've accidentally saw your comment.

Comment: " In their comments those 2 members, hinted to move out of the site, albeit subtly," -- It is unfortunate if that really happened ... but not tolerated here .. none can ask you to leave the site.. If you have already not flagged those comments, then I suggest that you wait at least till Pandya becomes active. Right now if you flag, flags will remain pending as Mods are not active now. @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: On that day I got so tired of seeing those comments and that of others.  The moderator remained silent on my earlier flags.  Now that I have made up my mind in taking exit, I am least bothered now about the action of the moderator. I have learned something from many members like you during my stay in this site.  Thanks once again for your cooperation @Rickross

Comment: Not a wise decision to take because of other users .. let's be patient and see what unfolds... If things do not change then gradually many users will naturally lessen their activities. @SrimannarayanaKV No one can stop them from doing that then

Comment: @srimannarayana kv - I don't get your passive aggressive whining of threatening to quit the site as seen above and comment in here https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/questions-asking-whether-something-is-an-interpolation-are-opinion-based-and-not#  Yes mods may not have a bias of action but main issue is that you feel slighted by a sect because you perceive they vote en masse against your posts that are grounded in esotericity as compared  to scriptures .

Comment: @srimannarayana kv - Not so long back you considered backing up answers with scriptures sectarian as can be made out from comments under https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1923/does-hinduism-se-promote-a-reductionist-approach-to-answering-questions/1928#1928 You have openly stated that you don't consider Puranas as valid sources . Members just flag or downvote and move on. No one is seen canvassing against you in meta for disregarding Puranas or saying mods are biased because they don't suspend a member who vilifies Puranas as sectarian literature

Comment: Hi! Rickross I'm sorry that I'm not posting any answers or comments since long, but I'm not completely inactive.. I do actually visit the main site in some time intervals to see the types of questions and answers posted nowadays (and they do not feel that great)... It might not be good to leave the site completely (as per my view)... some days, months, years we might be dormant.. I think we should have discussion in some chat room regarding how we should proceed further and how to further maintain the site.. Sorry for replying late.. I didn't use to visit meta.. so just saw your question now..

Comment: Hi thanks@Tejaswee Your points are all valid and I agree with all of them. I also don't like the idea of completely leaving the site. Taking breaks for some months is my way. :D

Comment: @Tejaswee I request you to nominate yourself for the Mod post. Will it possible for you?

Comment: @Rickross Hi! Thank you for considering me worthy as a moderator... But currently I'm sorry to say that I won't be able to handle this moderation (due to other work loads, exams etc...) Actually I request you to nominate yourself for the Mod post if it is possible for you...

Comment: Oh that's sad to know. It would have been great if you become a Mod. For me too there some problems, hence I can not commit. I am hoping for Destroyer to come back. I hope he has not taken up Sannyasa :D @Tejaswee

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you guys :) but I am not completely inactive on the site. I am visiting the site in some interval. But yes you are right @Rickross, my participation is very low these days. I will try to put my best.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani no problem bro .. take your time 

Answer (score 7):

According to site statistics, the member and the moderator [The Destroyer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer) was last seen on September 22 at 15:28.

If I remembered correctly, I was invited by him during 2015 with name ***Anil***.  As age is telling upon my memory, I don't know whether I remembered his name correctly or not.  He himself stated so, under this question - [Why is Hinduism SE not expanding?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411/3869)

> It was me who suggested you to visit this site. – The Destroyer♦ Nov
> 18 '15 at 13:28

As it was he, who brought me to this site, I think I should say ***Good Bye*** to this site, by mentioning his name.

**Good Bye**.

Comment: No need to be in hurry. He might be having some issues. He is still the Moderator, so he has not left the site. So no need for you to leave the site either.

Comment: take care Srimannarayana

Comment: Why are you leaving?

Comment: The Destroyer is active again. So, you should also return isn't it? I'm not sure whether you will get to see my comment or not but I hope you do and reconsider your decision of leaving the site :)