# List of avid users who are silent (and possibly chat with them)

Tags: discussion, users

From [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2007/has-the-moderator-the-destroyer-lost-all-interest-in-the-site) question, the following is the list of some avid users who are not much active in our main site

[Keshav Srinivasan♦](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan)

[Tejaswee](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/5154/tejaswee)

[The Destroyer♦](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer)

[Triyugi Narayan Mani](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4038/triyugi-narayan-mani)

Along with them, I personally feel that some other users like

[Mr. Alien](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/124/mr-alien)

[iammilind](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/1049/iammilind)

are also silent. This may not be a complete list.

Are there any other users you know that helped a lot during the initial days of our main site and are silent now?

My intention of asking this question is multi-fold. Key reason is that (relatively) new users should have an idea about such users who helped a lot to the site building and are silent now.

**Note**: I opened a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118501/request-for-avid-users) inorder to chat with avid users, if they join. If you are already familiar with any person previously, you can try to chat with them regarding their silence.

Comment: Oh! seems not a nice idea. My intention is to let new users know about them.

Comment: tbh new users should learn how this site works first. These people they will get to know anyway once they start browsing Q/A.

Comment: @Mr. Alien Is it possible for you to participate in our main site activities like before?

Comment: Hi @hanugm, thank you for taking some time out and mentioning some of the names who has contributed immensely in the early days of Hinduism. What's my reason of staying away? Lately, I'm a bit caught up with personal and professional goals and hence, I do not get free time often to hop in here or even Stackoverflow to help other users. While I deeply regret it, I hope I can get some free time in near future, where I will plan to hop in back and help the community to grow. Until then, feel free to ping me, I often check the pings and comments people leave for me and will try to help if I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mr.Alien for responding :) We are hoping the same based on your personal comfort only....

Comment: [Sarvabhouma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/5212/sarvabhouma) is also inactive from last 6-7 months..

Answer (score 3):

> Key reason is that (relatively) new users should have an idea about such users who helped a lot to the site building and are silent now.

I don't think they should know about those users. But since I am a programmer, I couldn't help myself but get you that list :)

Here is the list of users who are inactive and has reputation more than 2000. Mr. Alien actually visited this site recently so his name is not here:

[image]

You can do it yourself by running this query or modifying it on data.stackexchange.com :)

```
SELECT 
DisplayName,
Reputation,
CreationDate
FROM Users
WHERE Reputation > 2000
AND LastAccessDate <= '2020-12-1'
AND CreationDate <= '2015-01-01'
ORDER BY Reputation DESC
```

Also, there are a total of `16,514` users out of which `11,386` users are Inactive!

If you are lucky, you might be able to catch these users who are signing in but showing no activity:

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) ................