# Research Paper as Sources

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations

Should Research papers (especially in reference to Hinduism in any form whatsoever), that are published on eminent or prestigious internet forums or magazines, be allowed and/or considered valid sources for citations purposes on HSE ?

Comment: May be we need to list those eminent or prestigious forums or magazines first. Then we as a community can decide on shortlisting from that list.

Comment: Absolutely. Articles published by peer-reviewed reputed journals on Hinduism should be considered as valid source.

Answer (score 3):

This is an opinion-based question. I am putting my opinion and by no means to hurt anyone's sentiments.

The research work is done by one of us. There may be new contributors who find research sources from the internet or any specific place but again they are also based on the aggregated opinion of a few people and don't justify the real truth from the Vedas, scriptures, and old texts. There are many translations available for different texts with differences in opinions.

This can be done, if anyone is referring those research papers and sources, he/she should verify them before exposing them to the community. In this way, at least they are verified at the initial step and the chances of errors will be minified.

Use trusted sources, from trusted Hindu scripture literature organizations, societies, which people believe in.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! You can have a look at the help centre about on-topic questions, how to answer as well as [Guidelines for new users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions) - basically for the main site.

Comment: "they are also based on the aggregated opinion of a few people and don't justify the real truth from the Vedas, scriptures, and old texts" -  I agree with this atm. So, I don't think we should even consider if this has been verified or not. In short, only scripture and guru's perspectives should be allowed. Research papers represent scientifically or historically.